# How to set write permission to some file on Windows Desktop application

Tags: windows, windows-installer, file-permissions, desktop

My program has configuration file - config.ini. Program need to change configuration during working.
Customer want to store this file not on temporary folder, because this is not clear for him, customer wan to use C:\Program Files\MyProgram to store configurtion file.
I have add initial config to MSI file and write config.ini directly to C:\Program Files\MyProgram
But on some system write permission to my config.ini file file is absent, need manually add write permission.
Maybe I need additional custom action, but what parameters allow set write attribute on my config file?
Or this is impossible at all and I need to use temporary folder to store my config.ini?

This is MSI file description for installer, pay attention that ReadOnly = False

```
        {
        "SourcePath" = "8:..\\Configure\\bin\\Debug\\Config.txt"
        "TargetName" = "8:Config.txt"
        "Tag" = "8:"
        "Folder" = "8:_B94BBAFAD00D4E03B091B793279F9330"
        "Condition" = "8:NOT FILEEXISTS1"
        "Transitive" = "11:FALSE"
        "Vital" = "11:TRUE"
        "ReadOnly" = "11:FALSE"
        "Hidden" = "11:FALSE"
        "System" = "11:FALSE"
        "Permanent" = "11:FALSE"
        "SharedLegacy" = "11:FALSE"
        "PackageAs" = "3:1"
        "Register" = "3:1"
        "Exclude" = "11:FALSE"
        "IsDependency" = "11:FALSE"
        "IsolateTo" = "8:"
        }
```

And this is installation result - ReadOnly=True.

[image: Read only]